# How to make action bar and button color to be the same?

Tags: android

I have action bar and button and I've set same color for action bar as for button. But when I run my app my button color is darker than color of action bar. Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

My code for action bar:

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00B2EE")));
```

And for button:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#00B2EE"/>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please add styles.xml content

Comment: @matias-elorriaga I've edited it.Please take a look.